# How can i resize my canvas image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, canvas, image-resizing

page 1:

```
 //Calls the function from page 2 and the callback image is set as the source of the control.

previewImage(current, function(img) {
    jQuery(".mapItem").attr("src",img.src);
});
```

page 2:

```
//The functions callback returns an image which we use in page 1 (above)

var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.drawImage(this.m_Images[i],0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
var t = new Image();
t.src = canvas.toDataURL();
callback(t);
```

The issue:

I have 2 JavaScript pages, the first one has an image control and the second one has a function that returns a callback as an image.

My control in page 1 `(.mapItem)` has a height and width of 75.2px (fixed). The image that is coming from the callback however will have a different size each time e.g one day it can be 200px * 300px and one day it can be 150px * 200px etc

How can I clip or CUT the image of the callback? I want the image (t) to zero (0) as x and y starting points and then clip the image where ever the .mapItem control height and width is.

I need this to be proportional ratio. So I can't just add the following code:

`context.drawImage(this.m_Images[i],0,0,72.5,72.5);` because this will ruin the image as we dont even know if it is square shaped.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the proportions of callback image and then apply them to the page 1 image thus:

Let's assume that the callback image is 300x200px.  The ratio of the image's height-to-width can be expressed as...

```
var ratio = callbackImage.height / callbackImage.width;
```

...or, in this case...

```
var ratio = 200 / 300; // 0.666...
```

We know the width of the page 1 canvas is 72.5 so we can apply the ratio to that value to determine the proportional height of the callback Image like so...

```
var canvasWidthHeight = 72.5;
var imageHeight = canvasWidthHeight * ratio; // 48.333...
```

To center the callback Image on the page 1 canvas calculate the `y` offset like so..

```
var y = (canvasWidthHeight - imageHeight) / 2;
```

...and now you can use the canvas drawImage method with these values...

```
context.drawImage(
    this.m_Images[i], 
    0, y, 
    canvasWidthHeight, imageHeight
);
```

If the callback image was higher than it was wide you'd apply the ratio the page 1 canvas dimensions to work out the `x` offset rather than the `y` offest.  If the callback image was square then its ratio would be 1.0 and you could simply paint it into the square page 1 canvas at

```
context.drawImage(
    this.m_Images[i],
    0, 0,
    canvasWidthHeight, canvasWidthHeight
);
```

All together the code might look something like this...

```
var image = this.m_Images[i];
var canvas = {
    width: 72.5,
    height: 72.5
};

var wh = 0;
var ratio = image.height / image.width;

if (image.width > image.height) { // landscape
    wh = canvas.width * ratio;
    context.drawImage(
       image,
       0, (canvas.height - wh) / 2,
       canvas.width, wh
    );
} else if (image.width < image.height) { // portrait
    ratio = image.width / image.height;
    wh = canvas.height * ratio;
    context.drawImage(
       image,
       (canvas.width - wh) / 2, 0,
       wh, canvas.height
    );
} else { // square
    context.drawImage(
        image,
        0, 0,
        canvas.width, canvas.height
    );
}
```

Hope that helps.  ;)

EDIT:  You may need to ensure that the `new Image()` has fully loaded before initiating the callback.  You can do this with the following snippet...

```
// callback preparation code as before...

var t = new Image();
t.addEventListener('load', function() {
    callback(this);
});
t.src = canvas.toDataURL();
```

Comment: Oh it works now :) thanks. in firefox i dont get any canvas image though. any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks. it works now :) in firefox i dont get any canvas image thought. any suggestions why? it works in IE and chrome only

Comment: @sarah333  I'm not sure why firefox is giving you trouble.  Perhaps you need to ensure that the `new Image` is fully loaded before initiating the callback. I'll edit my answer with some additional code.

Comment: @sarah333 I also neglected a comma and the recalculation of the ratio for the 'portrait' condition.  All should be good now.  :)